# Bulk data upload in SharePoint Form Library

Tags: sharepoint-online, infopath, form, file-upload, bulk

I have a newly created Form management system(form Library) in SharePoint online. Prior to this the data was used to maintain in Excel sheets. We need to upload this old data into new Form library as list or form. 
If we consider the excel sheet's data as forms, then there will be more that 300 forms that we have to upload in this new system and with each form there will be some attached documents.

can any one suggest,if there is option of bulk upload for this task.

Comment: Hi did you find a way for bulk import data from excel to infopath forms, I am looking for a way?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is a way to bulk upload the attachments, especially out of the box.  But you can copy and paste the Excel data, if the columns match up perfectly.  Then it is a matter of editing each list item (form) to attach the documents via drag/drop for that item.